# Is there a way to grab questions, or at least "choice" options from Excel?

Tags: excel, office365, microsoft-forms

When creating a form in Microsoft Forms, one of the question types is "choice" (which can be set to offer radio buttons, checkouts or dropdowns as response types).

The default Forms interface provides for adding the answer options for these "choice" questions manually.

For long lists, e.g. names of countries, adding these options manually (not to mention sorting) is rather a chore.

Is there a way to tell Microsoft Forms to grab the list of options from Excel, e.g. a particular column in a particular sheet in a particular Excel file (Office 365). Ideally, this connection would be live, so that changing the cells in that column/range would change the options in the Form (yes, I see the problem).

To clarify, in my example, if I list the countries in Excel, sort them the way I want, copy the list, and paste it into an option in Forms, that works to add each Excel cell pasted as a separate option, which resolves many use case, but not for the "live" updation of the form as described above.

As a corollary, is it possible to "set up" all questions in Excel, and then sort-of import the question set into Forms?

I realize it is possible that this question is not necessarily a coding question and might be better suited for Power User. If so, I apologize.

Comment: I used randbetween() to pick 1 out of 5 questions, also used choose() to pick which set ie column. check them out.